# Can a Drupal based website's schema be imported to Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drupal, schema

I'm working on a web site that needs to be re-written in Rails. The website was before in Drupal, and there are almost 100,000 records in the database. Now, in Drupal there are tables that do not make any place in Rails in my opinion. For example,

```
Table name:  node_type
It stores information regarding modules in Drupal.
Table name: node
It stores information for node(s) in Drupal.
Table name: semaphore # I've no idea what it is!
Table name: rdf_mapping # No idea
```

I've not been working with Drupal, so all I want to ask: Is it possible to have a schema for Rails, in which the existing 100,000 records can be imported from Drupal? If so, how? If not so, what are the other options that I'm left with? Or I have to design an entirely new database schema?

Comment: You need to write a script to import the records from the Drupal database to your Rails one anyway so you might as well take the time to treat it with care and design a schema that fits your needs best.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal's database schema is not extensively documented for a reason... it's considered implementation details, is not a public API and should not be accessed directly, especially by outside application.

It is also very hard to document because for a given site, any enabled module can add its own tables and alter existing ones (usually adding columns). Plus you have module like Fields (part of Drupal core) that create tables dynamically depending on defined content types.

For a RoR developer, the Drupal schema will probably look weird and be uncomfortable to work with. I would follow suggestion from others, create a new schema for your new application and create a migration script to get the data from the old Drupal database to your new database. I don't knwon about RoR, but try to find a good data migration that allows replay, updates and rollback, etc. You will probably have to migrate the data multiple times to fixes bugs in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't have straight forward answers, but I have some ideas what I would do simply to not make so much changes in the database, or as per the comment you can write down an sql script to migrate the data according to the rails schema like types for each tables. Now,  I am just intended here to share my thoughts, but I believe there might be more explicit solutions and this is do-able in many ways, may be you need some customizations(?) overriding the default conventions. According to my thoughts, you can try the following things.

- 1. Generated Related model skipping migrations
- 2. Define tables explicitly to each models like the following snippets:

  `class Semaphore < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "semaphore"
  end`
- 3. You have to define foreign keys and primary keys explicitly for both record id and associations.
- 4. You have generate time stamp or you can explicitly avoid that like the following ways

  `ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = false`

These are basic things I can see is important.

Comment: What about the conventions in Rails? For file uploading, I've to use a gem say `paperclip` in Rails that automatically generates a table for me. How can I match it to the file related tables in Drupal's schema?

Comment: That can be synced too I guess! or you might need to write a rake task to upload those attachments again using the rails model to migrate those. Well, this is what I can think so far.